# Invalid conversion from throwing function of type Swift 2

Tags: swift

I migrated my app to Swift 2 and I get the error

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type

on the following line:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
```

Here's the full code block:

```
 NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
    response, data, error in

    let image = UIImage(data: data!)

    self.profilePic.image = image

    if var realUser = user {

        realUser["image"] = data as! AnyObject

        try realUser.save()

        FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({
            connection, result, error in

            realUser["first_name"] = result["first_name"]
            realUser["last_name"] = result["last_name"]

            try realUser.save()  
        })
    }
})
```

How do I fix this code with the new catch implemented in Swift 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
response, data in

let image = UIImage(data: data!)

self.profilePic.image = image

if var realUser = user {

    realUser["image"] = data as! AnyObject

    do {
        try realUser.save()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({
        connection, result, error in

        realUser["first_name"] = result["first_name"]
        realUser["last_name"] = result["last_name"]

    do {
        try realUser.save()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    })
}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The block passed to `sendAsynchronousRequest` is not allowed to throw errors. So you have to catch the errors:

```
do {
    try realUser.save()
}
catch {
    // handle the error
}
```